# Snowflake PrivateLink Setup

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm setting up VPC Endpoint for Snowflake PrivateLink. I'm following https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/admin-security-privatelink.html and https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/Invalid-certificate-error-reported-for-PrivateLink-hosts.

After I've configured VPC endpoint and Route 53 private hosted zone. I test the connection by provisioned an ec2 instance, sshed into the instance and run the following command

1. nslookup {my-account}.{region}.privatelink.snowflakecomputing.com, and I got

```
Server:         10.0.0.2
Address:        10.0.0.2#53

Non-authoritative answer:
<my-account>.<region>.privatelink.snowflakecomputing.com   canonical name = prod2-wildcard-1407098313.<region>.elb.amazonaws.com.
Name:   prod2-wildcard-1407098313.<region>.elb.amazonaws.com
Address: ...
Name:   prod2-wildcard-1407098313.<region>.elb.amazonaws.com
Address: ...
Name:   prod2-wildcard-1407098313.<region>.elb.amazonaws.com
Address: ...
```

2. run `SELECT SYSTEM$WHITELIST_PRIVATELINK();` and store result to `whitelist.json`, and run `snowcd whitelist.json` and I got

```
Error: x509: certificate is valid for *.<region>.snowflakecomputing.com, *.snowflakecomputing.com, *.global.snowflakecomputing.com, *.prod1.<region>.aws.snowflakecomputing.com, *.prod2.<region>.aws.snowflakecomputing.com, *.<region>.aws.snowflakecomputing.com, not <my-account>.<region>.privatelink.snowflakecomputing.com
```

3. Then I run curl -v ..privatelink.snowflakecomputing.com, and I got

```
* Server certificate:
*  subject: CN=*.<region>.snowflakecomputing.com
*  start date: Jul 21 00:00:00 2020 GMT
*  expire date: Aug 21 12:00:00 2021 GMT
*  subjectAltName does not match <my-account>.<region>.privatelink.snowflakecomputing.com
* SSL: no alternative certificate subject name matches target host name '<my-account>.<region>.privatelink.snowflakecomputing.com'
```

4. Then I run `sudo openssl s_client -connect <my-account>.<region>.privatelink.snowflakecomputing.com:443 -showcerts`, and I got

```
depth=4 ...
verify return:1
depth=3 ...
verify return:1
depth=2 ...
verify return:1
depth=1 ...
verify return:1
depth=0 CN = *.<region>.snowflakecomputing.com
verify return:1
```

Does anyone know What did I miss here? Thanks

Comment: This might be a silly question, but did you work with Snowflake Support to get PrivateLink setup on the Snowflake side?

Answer (score 0):

For Private Link setup, some steps need to be done by Snowflake support team as detailed here : https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/copy-into-location.html

```
Non-authoritative answer:
<my-account>.<region>.privatelink.snowflakecomputing.com   canonical name = prod2-wildcard-1407098313.<region>.elb.amazonaws.com.
Name:   prod2-wildcard-1407098313.<region>.elb.amazonaws.com
```

This error implies that the configuration is incomplete otherwise *wildcard* would not be listed in the results.